# Как сменить значение по-умолчанию для GPS во время поиска координат?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, есть GPS данные которые отражаются в виде широты 56,1922 и долготы 37,8615. Алгоритм работы такой когда GPS приёмник ВКЛЮЧЕН И НАХОДИТЬСЯ В ПОИСКЕ КООРДИНАТ нажимается кнопка для вывода результата который получается в виде null null. Необходимо что бы данный результат выводился в виде 00,0000 00,0000. Танцы с условиями и сравнениями почему то не работают.

```
protected void onResume() {// В onResume ВЕШАЕМ СЛУШАТЕЛЯ НА ПРОВАЙДЕРА С ПОМОЩЬЮ МЕТОДА requestLocationUpdates
    super.onResume();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER/*ТИП ПРОВАЙДЕРА*/,// НА ВХОД ЕМУ ПОДАЁМ
            1000 * 10/*МИНИМАЛЬНОЕ ВРЕМЯ ЗАПРОСА КООРДИНАТ*/, 10/*РАСТОЯНИЕ ОТОЙДЯ НА КОТОРОЕ ОБНОВЛЯЮТСЯ КООРДИНАТЫ*/, locationListener);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {//ОТКЛЮЧАЕМ СЛУШАТЕЛЯ МЕТОДА removeUpdates
    super.onPause();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}

private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {//LocationListener СЛУШАТЕЛЬ РЕАЛИЗУЕТ ИНТЕРФЕЙС locationListener СО СЛЕДУЮЩИМИ МЕТОДАМИ

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {//МЕТОД onLocationChanged НОВЫЕ ДАННЫЕ О МЕСТО ПОЛОЖЕНИИ
        showLocation(location);                       //ЗДЕСЬ ВЫЗЫВАЕМ СВОЙ МЕТОД showLocation(location)КОТОРЫЙ НА ЭКРАНЕ ОТОБРОЗИТ ДАННЫЕ О МЕСТО ПОЛОЖЕНИИ
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {//УКАЗАНЫЙ ПРОВАЙДЕР БЫЛ ОТКЛЮЧОН ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЕМ
        checkDisabled1();
        checkDisabled2();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {//УКАЗАНЫЙ ПРОВАЙДЕР БЫЛ ВКЛЮЧОН ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЕМ

    }

};

private void showLocation(Location location) {
    if (location == null)
        return;

    dataGPS1 = formatLocation1(location);
    dataGPS2 = formatLocation2(location);
}

public String formatLocation1(Location location) {// НА ВХОД БЕРЁТ Location location
    if (location == null)                         //ЧЕТАЕТ ИЗ НЕГО ДАННЫЕ И ВЫДАЁТ СТРОКУ
        return "";                                //ШИРОТА, ДОЛГОТА, ВРЕМЯ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ
    return String.format(
            "%1$.4f",
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

}

public String formatLocation2(Location location) {// НА ВХОД БЕРЁТ Location location
    if (location == null)                         //ЧЕТАЕТ ИЗ НЕГО ДАННЫЕ И ВЫДАЁТ СТРОКУ
        return "";                                //ШИРОТА, ДОЛГОТА, ВРЕМЯ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ
    return String.format(
            "%2$.4f",
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

}

private void checkDisabled1() {//ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕТ ВКЛЮЧЕНЫ ИЛИ ВЫКЛЮЧЕНЫ ПРОВАЙДЕРЫ МЕТОДОМ isProviderEnabled
    dataGPS1 = "00,0000";//И ОТОБРАЖАЕТ ЭТУ НФОРМАЦИЮ НА ЭКРАНЕ

}

private void checkDisabled2() {//ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕТ ВКЛЮЧЕНЫ ИЛИ ВЫКЛЮЧЕНЫ ПРОВАЙДЕРЫ МЕТОДОМ isProviderEnabled
    dataGPS2 = "00,0000";//И ОТОБРАЖАЕТ ЭТУ НФОРМАЦИЮ НА ЭКРАНЕ

}
```

Comment: Вы уже задавали этот вопрос.

Comment: @metalurgus это новый вопрос по тому же коду.

Comment: @metalurgus в прошлом вопросе вы мне подсказали как сменить значение когда GPS выключен сей час мне интересно знать как сменить значение когда GPS находится в поиске координат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void showLocation(Location location) {
    if (location == null) {
        dataGPS1 = "00,0000";
        dataGPS2 = "00,0000";
        return;
    }

    dataGPS1 = formatLocation1(location);
    dataGPS2 = formatLocation2(location);
}
```

---

Если хотите решить не правильно, а быстро (при помощи костыля), то можете попробовать так:
Перед этой строкой:

```
file = new File(directory.getPath() + "/" + " " + dataGPS1 + " " + dataGPS2 + " " + ".jpg");
```

добавьте это:

```
if(dataGPS1 == null) {
    dataGPS1 = "00,0000";
}
if(dataGPS2 == null) {
    dataGPS2 = "00,0000";
}
```

В этом случае можете убрать изменения для ситуации, когда GPS выключен, которые вы сделали после предыдущего вопроса.

П.С. Код у вас мягко сказать *немного странный*. Очень некрасивый и непонятный.

Comment: Не хочу ничего плохого сказать, но этот вариант не работает не работал он когда вы мне его в первый раз предложили ещё раз уточню, что танцы с условиями и сравнениями почему то не работают. Может код и не красивый, но как он может быть не понятным когда в нём каждый метод за комментирован ?

Comment: @VargSieg, может вы тогда покажете все-таки **полный код**? Вы не показываете кусок, где вы отменяете GPS, ипользуете 'dataGPS1 '

Comment: Так это и есть полный код всего блока методов отвечающий за GPS результат его работы сохраняется в переменные типа String GPS1 и GPS2  а после выводится в имя файла `file = new File(directory.getPath() + "/" + " "
                        + dataGPS1 + "    " + dataGPS2 + "  "  + ".jpg");`

Comment: Может проще такой вопрос как добиться что бы данная конструкция ` return String.format(
            "%2$.4f",
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());` в место null возвращала 00,0000 ?

Comment: @VargSieg, важно то, в каком месте вы вызываете этот код. Очевидно же, что просто на момент вызова кода в переменные + dataGPS1 + " " + dataGPS2 ничего не было записано. Можете прямо перед вызовом этого кода проверить, есть там что-то, или нет.

Comment: @VargSieg Я отредактировал ответ

Comment: @VargSieg, конструкция  `return String.format( "%2$.4f", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());` у вас просто не вызывается в случае, если GPS выключен, или координаты не определены